# Logically disable Drag on react-native-draggable-flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface, react-native-flatlist, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I'm trying to disable the drag feature based on some props change, not sure how to disable/enable it on 'react-native-draggable-flatlist', please find below the code

```
import DraggableFlatList from 'react-native-draggable-flatlist'
    <DraggableFlatList
      scrollPercent={5}
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item: any) => `draggable-item-${item}`}
      onMoveEnd={({ data }: any) => {
        this.setState({ data })
      }}
    />
```

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist/issues/72) might help.

Comment: @SMAKSS - Not working, tried all the possible steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my requirement, I have totally disabled the parent component and it worked, but still not sure if there are any ways to disable it by passing a particular prop